# DHCP help in Virtual Box

Tags: dhcp, virtualbox-networking

new to Linux and Ubuntu - ya noob, be gentle.

I have a Windows 7 host, running latest Virtual Box, created an Ubuntu 12.10 server installation.  Everything seemed to go fine, I chose all defaults both for the Virtual box settings and for the Ubuntu server install. I only chose to add Samba file server and LAMP installs.

I chose the default network adapter in Vbox, only 1 adapter set for NAT  - but I don't believe the ubuntu server install is binding properly.

Forum won't let me paste a screen shot - effectively ifconfig shows no IP address bound on eth0.  In /etc/network/interfaces config I didn't change anything, and it has eth0 bound to dhcp - so seems like that is default setting.

I'm just trying to learn ubuntu, so want a very basic setup - what did I miss to bind the network adapter? Did a search here in forums first, couldn't find a related post.

Any suggestions welcome, thx

Comment: I reset Vbox for additional adapter with NAT for loopback. I did get a binding, although the ip address was on different subnet and I can't ping in or out of the vm.  I think my question is a Vbox issue now, so I'll jump over to their forums -- unless anyone here can help. I am trying to build a lamp server to learn in a vm. I need to hit the apache web server on the ubuntu vm from the Windows 7 host, so making sure communication can happen between host and guest is essential. thx for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

- if you have DHCP running on your network and want your Vbox Guest to get its IP from that. on your VBox Seling your VM click Setting Bridge adapter this will emulate the VM like it has a separate Lancard.

Hope this helps